# What is the best model to mysql - django - android?

Tags: python, android, mysql, django

I do my personal project.
The project is

1. Sign up at Android.
2. Android send sign up information to MySQL
3. When sign in at Android, request information.
4. Server receive login request, server get login data from MySQL
5. When server get login data, server compare login data

   5-1. if login data and request information right, send correct

   5-2. if login data and request information wrong, send wrong

I designed model like this:

> MySQL - Django - Android

But I don't have any idea how to code this

This is my practice code. model.py

```
from django.db import models

class FidoAccount(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    CrewId = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Company = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Code = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

views.py

```
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from .models import FidoAccount
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.shortcuts import render
import json

class SavetoDB(View):
    def get(self, request): # 값을 받아온다(db에서)
        faccount = FidoAccount.objects.all().order_by('-id') #object가 쿼리셋

        data = json.loads(serialize('json', faccount))
        return JsonResponse({'Information': data})

    def post(self, request):
        if request.META['CONTENT_TYPE'] == "application/json":
            request = json.loads(request.body)
            faccount = FidoAccount(Name = request['Name'],
                                  CrewId = request['CrewId'],
                                  Company = request['Company'],
                                  Code = request['Code'])

        else:
            faccount = FidoAccount(Name=request.POST['Name'],
                                  CrewId=request.POST['CrewId'],
                                  Company=request.POST['Company'],
                                  Code=request.POST['Code'])
            faccount.save() # db에 저장.
            return HttpResponse(status=200)

class htmlview(View):
    def get(self, request):
        filter = FidoAccount.objects.filter(title="Name") # name필드의 값을 가져온다
        data = json.loads(serialize('json', filter))
        return JsonResponse({'filter': data})
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problems a few months ago and i found it was easier to authenticate using the default user model in django rather than create your own model.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/deno101/32508156e373350b1a30304e34120467) of my forms.py and views.py files.